# Error in using Intel OpenCL sdk debugger

Tags: debugging, opencl, intel

I am trying to debug an opencl code with the Intel opencl sdk debugger plugin for visual studio 2008 prof edition.

I am getting a build program error with this code

Err = clBuildProgram(cpProgram, 0, NULL, "-g -s \"C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.2\OpenCL\src\oclVectorAdd\VectorAdd.cl\"", NULL, NULL);

Can anybody help me ?

My device type is CPU.. I7 system..

Comment: What does your kernel look like?  What exact error text are you getting? Were you able to run a simple OpenCL kernel (such as SampleCL) on your system?

Comment: i can run a simple kernel when i use 
errNum=(clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL));

but i get a build error code -11 when i use
Err = clBuildProgram(cpProgram, 0, NULL, "-g -s \"C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.2\OpenCL\src\oclVectorAdd\VectorAdd.cl\"", NULL, NULL);

Comment: The -g and -s flags are not supported by OpenCL.  Why do you have them?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to uninstall NVIDIA SDK 4.2 and then install Intel SDK. The Intel SDK Only Support Intel cores and Intel Graphics and NVIDIA SDK Only Support NVIDIA Graphics (Not Intel cores!)

Answer (score 0):

Your path should be this when you write it in C & C++ (escaping the `\` with another `\`):

```
"-g -s \"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\NVIDIA Corporation\\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.2\\OpenCL\\src\\oclVectorAdd\VectorAdd.cl\""
```

Comment: Is not the same since only one "\" will cause an error because, it is a special character. To indicate a path you should always use doubled "\\"